# Any available master server in GtaCoop?

Tags: server

I can't host servers. It only shows that "Masterserver is not available at the time...". I hosted a MasterServer for myself but it isn't working too. What can I do?

Comment: what is the code you tried so far?

Comment: Please skim [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and clarify your question. Then we can give an answer to your question.